# Why are my Bootstrap modal images not showing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build an extremely simple image gallery with bootstrap 3.

It is just a few thumbnails and when you click on one of them, a modal window appearing on top with the real size image.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for foto in fotos %}
            <div class="col-md-2 ">
                <a href="#launch{{loop.index}}" data-toggle="modal">
                    <img class="photo-grid" src="{{foto.thumb_url}}" border="0">
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% for foto in fotos %}
    <section id="launch{{loop.index}}" class="modal hide fade">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="{{foto.big_url}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endfor %}
```

So basically it is a Jinja2 template receiving a list of information with links to images.

The thumbnail images are showing properly, but when I click on one of them I expect to see a modal window appearing on top and showing the image in bigger size. But that is not happening.

I have checked that the data `foto.thumb_url` and `foto.big_url` are correct.

THis is how I import Bootstrap:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas on what I am missing in my code?

Comment: It's difficult to say given you say your paths are correct and there's no CSS to see if something is overwriting the photo-grid class. Images do work inside bootstrap modal windows you can view something I'm working on at http://triplewww.com/startbs/ ... first thumb in the portfolio section.

Comment: I have edited my message showing how I import the Bootstrap files. And there is not much more to it. I haven't written any extra CSS. I will take a look at your work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
<a href="#launch{{loop.index}}" data-toggle="modal">
```

to

```
<a href="#" data-target="#launch{{loop.index}}" data-toggle="modal">
```

Bootstrap needs the data-toggle attribute with the modal ID to know which modal to open. Checkout this JSFiddle, I tweaked your stuff just a little http://jsfiddle.net/9A6uA/